# Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned 800700C1

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webdriver

Every time I launch Selenium WebDriver on one of my test servers, I'm receiving the following error from the SDK:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException:
Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned
800700C1 for URL 'http://localhost:5555/' (NoSuchDriver).
```

The rest of my test servers are not having any trouble. Also, I verified that all of the internet zones were set to protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Delete the "C:\Program" file from your system

Answer from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6181

It seems a bit odd, but when I checked, there was a 0 byte "Program" file in the root of the C drive. I deleted the file and the issue went away.